# Supernatual Stamina + Commander

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I've been wondering a seemingly stupid question, can [Supernatural Stamina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSupernatural%20Stamina%5d) work more than once on a commander card? Instant grants ability to creature, commander is the same creature while changing zones. Could it be a loophole or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can not use [Supernatural Stamina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSupernatural%20Stamina%5d) to return your Commander to the battlefield multiple times.**

Whenever a creature leaves the battlefield and returns it is treated as different object. This is covered in the gatherer rulings for Supernatural Stamina:

> Supernatural Stamina’s effect works only once. If the targeted creature dies and is then returned to the battlefield, it’s considered to be a new creature. If that new creature dies, it won’t come back a second time.

---

Additionally, while your Commander is still considered your Commander while changing zones it is still treated as a new object every time it changes zones as covered in the comprehensive rules:

> **903.3.**: Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.

and:

> **400.7.**: An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule:*

<sub>**(None of the exceptions apply)*</sub>

Comment: Note: It's not just the triggered ability the "returned Commander" won't have; it won't have the +2/+0 for the same reason.

Comment: Nit: Technically, one of the exceptions of 400.7 does apply here, at least in the first zone change. 400.7h allows the ability to find the object in the graveyard.

Comment: Additionally I would like to know if this then applies the 2 manna penalty to cast him again? The commander didn't technically hit the command zone again does that mean his cost will be unchanged?

Comment: @ThunderToes The rules say that "Doing so costs that player an additional {2} for each previous time he or she cast that commander from the command zone that game." So since you haven't cast it from the command zone an additional time, the cost doesn't go up. Note that it doesn't count how many times the commander has been in the command zone, but how many times it's been cast from there. Thus, theoretically, if you can find some way to get it into play from the command zone without actually casting it, the cost doesn't go up.

Comment: @Arthur relevant to that would be Derevi or Command Beacon.

Comment: @ikegami RE:Nit, that is true, but I didn't want to complicate things.

Answer (score 2):

Supernatural Stanima will only protect a creature once; there is nothing different or special about a Commander here.

If you want to use Supernatural Stamina on your commander, then when it is killed; you must choose not to send it to the command zone instead of to the graveyard. If you choose to send it to the command zone, then it will never die, so Supernatural Stanima would do nothing. If you choose not to send it to the command zone, then it will return like any other creature would; but no longer be protected.

From the glossary in the rules:

> **Dies**
>
> > A creature “dies” if it is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.

So a commander that goes to your command zone won't have died.